# How to check the MSMQ messagebody is valid or not

Tags: .net, msmq

Iam new to .Net and working on MSMQ

I want to check whether the body of a message receives is valid or not , so I am doing a validation " msmqMessage.Body == null " , but this throws exception .
I also found that the bodytype is 0 when this happens other wise it will be 768

So is it ok to check whether the bodytype ==0 for invalid message .

I dont know what does 0 and 768 stands for , from where i can get differnt values for bodytype and what does it represent?

Comment: mmm, should have asked my question on this side. Is your sender and receiver both .NET based?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you set 'BodyType' yourself (from the other side).

What constitutes 'valid' for you? Is it that the object is of a specific type? perhaps check for that.

Who else is writing objects to your queue, and what type are they?

Comment: Explicitly I didnt set the bodytype any where , formatter set to BinaryMessageFormatter , then send the message .

Is it mandatory to set the bodytype ?

It will be helpful if you could help me to find the definition of '0' ,768  and other numerical values if any

Comment: I never set the BodyType, but I also never check it. I am also using a BinaryMessageFormatter. My other question remains - who else sends messages into your queue?

Comment: Did anyone manage to figure this out? I have the same problem - messages with BodyType=0 are breaking my program

Comment: I would like to know, is the sender and the receiver both .NET based?